# dcos - kafka broker add - No such command "add"

Tags: dcos

Tried to setup a dcos kafka broker as such:

```
bash-3.2$ dcos kafka broker list
bash-3.2$ dcos package list
NAME       VERSION        APP         COMMAND    DESCRIPTION
cassandra  1.0.1-2.2.5    /cassandra  cassandra  Apache Cassandra running on DC/OS
kafka      1.0.2-0.9.0.1  /kafka      kafka      Apache Kafka running on DC/OS
spark      1.6.1-6        /spark      ---        Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data.  Documentation: https://docs.mesosphere.com/usage/managing-services/spark/
bash-3.2$ dcos kafka broker add 1
Usage: dcos-kafka kafka broker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: No such command "add".
bash-3.2$
```

what should I check?

Comment: What does `dcos --version` give you? Also, are you using DC/OS 1.7 EA from dcos.io? Check out https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/tutorials/kafka/ in this case, CLI has changed.

Comment: dcos version 0.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to use DC/OS 1.7 with CLI version `0.4.4` the answer to your problem is that you're using an outdated interface: both the Kafka service and the CLI have changed and you should follow the steps outlined in the new [Kafka service guide](https://docs.mesosphere.com/kafka-1-7/). The [Kafka usage tutorial](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/usage/tutorials/kafka/) is also a nice way to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting to the newest version in DC/OS 1.7 is of course recommended, but if you cannot do it or it gives you trouble, you can force the old version by installing the framework with a specified older version like `dcos package install --package-version=0.9.4.0 kafka`